# Subject-Verb Agreement

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Sentence that needs correction:

> Sensationalism in television shows masquerading as "news" programs **are** making it difficult for serious journalism to compete for ratings.

The correction should be *sensationalism...is*. I don't see how the use of *are* is incorrect. What's wrong with the sentence above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subject is *Sensationalism*. Everything between *sensationalism* and *is* is  modifier on *Sensationalism*:

> *What kind of sensationalism?* ... Sensationalism in television shows.
>   *What kind of television shows?* ... Television shows masquerading as "news" programs.

It is the sensationalism in those shows which makes things difficult for serious journalists.

Comment: Sensationalism in television shows masquerading as "news" programs is making it difficult for serious journalism to compete for ratings. In this sentence, the verb should be "is" because the subject is singular. Please correct me if I mentioned wrong

Answer (score 7):

The subject of the sentence is the first word: "Sensationalism". This is a singular noun, so the verb "is" fits.

The reason "are" sounds right is because the object of the prepositional phrase "in television shows" as well as the predicate of the modifying clause "masquerading as 'news' programs" are both plural. However, the real subject is "sensationalism", with which the verb must agree.

Comment: could programs be the verb that agrees with are?

Comment: No. There can only be one verb in a clause. Clauses don't have to "agree" grammatically, but it *is* good practice to match the tense and voice of verbs in compound sentences. This is not a compound sentence. There is one independent clause "Sensationalism is" with one dependent clause in the subject and another in the predicate. It is very confusing.

Comment: what's the dependent clause?

Comment: In the subject: Shows masquerading as news programs. In the predicate: making it difficult to compete for ratings. I don't know, the gerund form of the verbs might classify them as phrases.

Comment: @Ben -- your mistake is "natural", and shows that your grasp of subject/verb agreement is becoming fluent.  Most native speakers have to be taught this lesson in elementary school, because they might not learn it on their own.

Comment: @Jasper is 100% correct. It is very common to hear native speakers make this mistake in conversation. English is difficult, especially for English-speakers.