# Do I use "is" or "are" when writing "(an energy) source is/are the ocean waves"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I'm writing about renewable energy sources and I'm having a bit of trouble with this sentence:

> A relatively immature, yet promising source are the ocean waves, which are a ceaseless discharge of energy directly on the shoreline.

Some grammar check services say that I should write:

> A relatively immature, yet promising source **is** the ocean waves, which are a ceaseless discharge of energy directly on the shoreline.

I think can understand why this is correct, since *"the source"* is singular, i should use *"is"*. But it seems a bit weird to use *"is"* when writing about *"the wave**s**"*. What is the correct form?

Comment: You might want to replace words *immature* and *discharge* with more felicitous ones. Nevertheless, we don't do proofreading here.

Comment: What do you mean by felicitous? Could you please give an example? And I'm sorry, I didn't mean to ask for proofreading.

Comment: I mean that they don't sound very good in this context. And don't worry. By the way, it's always a good thing to wait a day or two before accepting an answer, because when other people see a question already has an accepted answer, they're less likely to try to answer it themselves. (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The verb must coordinate with the (singular) subject:

> *A ... source is the ... waves...*

You could rewrite it with a (plural) subject:

> *The ... waves are a ... source...*

Possibly a duplicate of [Subject-Verb Agreement](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/30932/subject-verb-agreement)